# Bluetooth audio becomes telephone-style bandpass filtered after having conversed in microsoft teams

Tags: bluetooth, microsoft-teams, opensuse, pulseaudio

It sounds like bluetooth has 2 audio modes, one bandpass filtered (not completely as terrible as telephone quality) and one that is music worthy, and that Microsoft Teams for Linux likes to switch to the worst of them without switching back.

How can I debug what's going on here, to figure out if this is a bug in Microsoft Teams or Pulseaudio? Or better, how to correct it? Pavucontrol doesn't seem to expose this state.

What I know:
If I want to listen to music inbetween calls, it doesn't help to reconnect the bluetooth headset unless I quit or restart Microsoft Teams first.

If it matters, I'm using OpenSuse Tumbleweed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always have `pavucontrol` open when switching between Teams and Spotify. The right-most tab "Configuration" has a profile setting for each output device.

Still, this is very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, bluetooth has different "profiles" for audio transmission, e.g. *HFP/HSP* for simultaneous (bad-quality) output and input, and *A2DP* for output-only.
You probably only have to switch back to A2DP after your call, using the "Configuration" tab in pavucontrol, or

`pactl set-card-profile bluez_card.$YOURMAC a2dp_sink`

Comment: Looks like a good tip! Unfortunately, pactl is just saying "Failure: No such entity" no matter what I try, and it's not as userfriendly as saying which of the two arguments is wrong.

Comment: @user2394284 `pactl list cards` shows all your cards, including a "profile" section for each listing the available profiles

Answer (score 0):

A way to debug: `pactl list sinks`. I don't know what to do about it, though.

Here is the change observed brom before and after a Teams call:

```
-Sink #12
-       State: RUNNING
-       Name: bluez_sink.00_09_A7_34_4F_A8.a2dp_sink
+Sink #11
+       State: SUSPENDED
+       Name: bluez_sink.00_09_A7_34_4F_A8.headset_head_unit
        Description: Beoplay H9i
        Driver: module-bluez5-device.c
-       Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
-       Channel Map: front-left,front-right
+       Sample Specification: s16le 1ch 8000Hz
+       Channel Map: mono
        Owner Module: 32
        Mute: no
-       Volume: front-left: 27525 /  42% / -22,61 dB,   front-right: 27525 /  42% / -22,61 dB
+       Volume: mono: 30584 /  47%
                balance 0,00
-       Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
-       Monitor Source: bluez_sink.00_09_A7_34_4F_A8.a2dp_sink.monitor
-       Latency: 47400 usec, configured 45317 usec
-       Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
+       Base Volume: 65536 / 100%
+       Monitor Source: bluez_sink.00_09_A7_34_4F_A8.headset_head_unit.monitor
+       Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
+       Flags: HARDWARE HW_VOLUME_CTRL LATENCY 
        Properties:
-               bluetooth.protocol = "a2dp_sink"
+               bluetooth.protocol = "headset_head_unit"
+               device.intended_roles = "phone"
                device.description = "Beoplay H9i"
@@ -241,3 +242,3 @@
        Ports:
-               headphone-output: Headphone (priority: 0, available)
+               headphone-output: Headphone (priority: 0)
        Active Port: headphone-output
```